# Laravel 5.2 how to run route on cron / php command line on linux?

Tags: php, laravel

Despite going through documentation about commands (is that how you can run php on command line on laravel?) I just don't get it at all.

For example I can run php script on command line on linux:

```
php /path/to/my/phpfile.php
```

How on earth I can manage to do this on laravel? Let's say I have a route to

```
Route::get('/runthis', array('as' => 'runthis', 'uses' => 'Controller@runthis'));
```

How to run this on cron?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150107/a-cron-job-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 3):

I would actually take a different approach to this personally. I would leverage the `schedule` method off of the Kernel and simply add `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run` It may look something like this:

In:

```
App
    |- Console
        |- Kernel.php
```

The structure of this file would look something like this:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
    protected $commands = [

    ];

    /* ... */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
        $schedule->call(function(){
            //call your logic here
        })->cron('* * * * *');
    }
}
```

Now just add the appropriate entry to your `crontab` and you're good to go.

**Updated with Cron Information**

`cron` tasks (AFAIK) don't support the `seconds` granularity. Instead, you would need to execute the cron task `30 times` 2 seconds after the previous in order to achieve the "every 2 seconds" cron job. There's no other way that I know of to achieve this.

Here is a [little diagram](https://serverfault.com/a/601660) that I've found extremely useful in explaining what the `asterisk` mean:

```
 * * * * *  command to execute
 ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬
 │ │ │ │ │
 │ │ │ │ │
 │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use     names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

And here's a list of your options you can use instead of `cron` as shortcuts:

```
->cron('* * * * * *');  Run the task on a custom Cron schedule
->everyMinute();    Run the task every minute
->everyFiveMinutes();   Run the task every five minutes
->everyTenMinutes();    Run the task every ten minutes
->everyThirtyMinutes(); Run the task every thirty minutes
->hourly(); Run the task every hour
->daily();  Run the task every day at midnight
->dailyAt('13:00'); Run the task every day at 13:00
->twiceDaily(1, 13);    Run the task daily at 1:00 & 13:00
->weekly(); Run the task every week
->monthly();    Run the task every month
->monthlyOn(4, '15:00');    Run the task every month on the 4th at 15:00
->quarterly();  Run the task every quarter
->yearly(); Run the task every year
->timezone('America/New_York'); Set the timezone
```

Comment: What is the meaning by star(*) in cron('* * * * *'); Please explain, i need to run cron on every two second.

Comment: @Mandy Big update to the post for you, I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy, but i have to schedule cron job for every 2 second. and it is not running automatically, I have run it from command prompt and it runs only one time from command prompt. Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

if you are scheduling with cron you can just use `curl "url"` to call the route

Comment: Actually yeah, that would work :). Thought could there be a "laravel way" though and it seems comands are the way to go, but I'm good with this as well I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't typically run a controller function in a cron. You'd put the `runthis` logic in [an Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-commands), then [schedule it to run](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#defining-schedules) with Laravel's scheduler.

Comment: Yeah.. Thought so it's with commands. I read that doc about commands and it didn't really help me forward but I read it again, thanks

Comment: @EmJeiEn Docs are pretty straightforward, what are you having trouble with? You'd essentially do something like `php artisan make:console RunThis`, modify the resulting `app/Console/Commands/RunThis.php` `handle()` function to do the functionality you want, and then something like `$schedule->command('runthis')->daily();` in your scheduler.